# Function defining answer by a vector

Tags: r, function

Looking to learn function writing. I have data laid out in the following (e.g.):

```
Genus Species  Wing  Tail
 A       X     10.5  20.3
 A       Y     10.7  20.7
 B       XX    15.2  22.5
 B       XY    15.5  24
```

I calculate variance for a given trait using the equation:

```
 sqrt(max(Wing) - min (Wing))
```

which I sum for all traits.

So I can write the following function so sum variance for the total data set:

```
variance<- function(data){
t   <- sqrt(max(Tail)-min(Tail))
w   <- sqrt(max(Wing)-min(Wing))
x <- sum(t,w)
x
}
```

But I can'twork out how to generate a response to give me an output where this result is dependant on the Genus. So i'm looking to generate an output like:

```
 Genus A    Genus B
  2.345      3.456
```

Comment: ah sorry, didnt realise about that function

Comment: And the variance of a random variable isn't the square root of the range.

Comment: To add to what Jack M. said:  you need to learn a bit more math, and spend the time to read through any of the excellent online "introduction and tutorial for R" pages.  If you really didn't stop to think that R would have a Variance and Std_deviation function, you are kind of missing the whole point.

Comment: I was using this definition as variance based on a paper published on the area im using. Using var() would just be substituted in,wasnt really worrying about that at the moment and isnt the question. I have several R books that I have been reading, and apparently I havn't been able to come up with a working solution. If you're willing to overlook these facts and help me learn this program, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @NickCrouch - The variance of a random variable `X` is `E((X-E(X))^2)` (where `E(X)` denotes the expected value of `X`).  `sqrt(max(X)-min(X))` is **not** the same thing as the variance of `X`.

Comment: Just curious: what's the reference for the paper?  I can believe that this measure of dispersion makes sense in **some** context, but it would be interesting to see the context ... (the negative comments you've been getting have something to do with the fact that this measure of dispersion looks pretty weird on the face of it -- it will tend to be very unstable (because extreme values like min/max are), and it's in strange (square-root) units

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to give a new name to your function because it's just wrong to call it "variance". I hope you can overlook that. We can work on a dataframe object

```
dput(dfrm)
structure(list(Genus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("X", "XX", "XY", "Y"), class = "factor"), Wing = c(10.5, 
10.7, 15.2, 15.5), Tail = c(20.3, 20.7, 22.5, 24)), .Names = c("Genus", 
"Species", "Wing", "Tail"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

dev2<- function(df){
    t   <- sqrt(max(df[["Tail"]])-min(df[["Tail"]]))
    w   <- sqrt(max(df[["Wing"]])-min(df[["Wing"]]))
    x <- sum(t,w)
   x
   }
```

Now use it to work on the full dataframe, using the split-lapply strategy, which passes sections of the original dataframe determined by the Genus values to the dev2 function

```
lapply( split(dfrm, list(dfrm$Genus)), FUN = dev2)
$A
[1] 1.079669

$B
[1] 1.772467
```